# Angular - Why am I getting object of objects instead of array of objects?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngrx, typescript-typings

Component:

```
applicants: UserProfile[];
ngOnInit() {
    this.store
      .pipe(select(fromRootUserProfileState.getUserProfiles))
      .subscribe((userProfiles: UserProfile[]) => {
        this.applicants = userProfiles;
        console.log('this.applicants:', this.applicants);
      });
}
```

UserProfile interface:

```
export interface UserProfile {
  id: number;
  fullName: string;
  roles?: Role[];
  windowsAccount?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  email?: string;
  managerName?: string;
  managerId?: number;
  managerEmail?: string;
  companyId?: number;
  companyName?: string;
  countryId?: number;
  country: Country;
  countryName?: string;
}
```

NgRx effect:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserProfileEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private userProfileService: UserProfileService
  ) {}
  @Effect()
  loadUserProfiles$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(userProfileActions.UserProfileActionTypes.LoadUPs),
    mergeMap((action: userProfileActions.LoadUPs) =>
      this.userProfileService.getUserProfiles().pipe(
        map(
          (userProfiles: Array<UserProfile>) =>
            new userProfileActions.LoadSuccessUPs(userProfiles)
        ),
        catchError((err) => of(new userProfileActions.LoadFailUPs(err)))
      )
    )
  );
}
```

The service:

```
getUserProfiles(): Observable<UserProfile[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserProfile[]>(this.baseUrl + 'userprofiles/getuserprofiles');
  }
```

Backend API (.Net Core):

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserProfiles()
{
var userProfiles = await _userProfileRepository.GetUserProfiles();
var userProfileViewModels = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserProfileViewModel>>(userProfiles);

return Ok(userProfileViewModels);
}
```

But in the component, I cannot treat my "applicants" array as a proper array, it is some sort of an object. This is happening all over my code, why am I not getting array of objects as I explicitly have defined?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post your console response?

Comment: I just added the snip at the end.

Comment: As I can see in the response its not an array, Its objects with index 0,1, 2 and so on. You can't use push function on objects. You need to check implementation, or if you can post in stackblitz.

Comment: The backend API method is also added.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest workaround for now. You can convert response to to array from below code.

```
for (var key in userProfiles ) {
    if (userProfiles.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var val = userProfiles[key];
        this.applicants.push(val)
    }
}
```

After this you can do push operation `applicants` variable.